# No value is writtern in my tcp client/server program

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, io

In my TCP socket program I have to send data from client to server. In server side I have to read the streams and write it in file. But File is created and nothing is written inside.

Client side coding to send file:

```
try
{

    Socket ss = new Socket("localhost", 5010);

    BufferedOutputStream put = new BufferedOutputStream(ss.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader st = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));

    File f = new File("e://read.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = fis.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1)
    {
        put.write(buf,0,read);
        put.flush();
    }
    //d.close();
    System.out.println("File transfered");
    ss.close();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Server to read the inputstream and write it in a file:

```
try
{
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5010);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    BufferedReader get = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    FileWriter writedata = new FileWriter("c://write.txt");

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writedata);

    String line=bw.toString();
    while ((line = get.readLine()) != null) {
        bw.write(line + "\n");
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: you forget to put `bw.close()` after the `while` statement

Comment: have you tried writing in append mode?  bw=new BufferedWriter(writedata, true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot bw.close and bw.flush....below is the code that works...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TestServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(5010);
        Socket s=ss.accept();
        BufferedReader get= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        FileWriter writedata=new FileWriter("c://Test//testoutput.txt");

        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(writedata);

        String line=bw.toString();
        while ((line = get.readLine()) != null) {

            bw.write(line + "\n");

        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}


import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TestClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {

           Socket ss=new Socket("localhost",5010);

           BufferedOutputStream put=new BufferedOutputStream(ss.getOutputStream());
           BufferedReader st=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));

           File f=new File("c://Test//testinput.txt");
           FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
           byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
           int read;
           while((read=fis.read(buf,0,1024))!=-1)
           {
               put.write(buf,0,read);
               put.flush();
           }
           //d.close();
           System.out.println("File transfered");
           ss.close();
           ss.close();


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.And It works. But only one character is written from the source file and not entire content

Comment: I tested the program I mentioned for variety of files and it works...please try running exact programs...

Comment: @Ameer This code only works for text files, and even for those it is liable to change the line terminators. It will corrupt binary files. In general you shouldn't use Readers and Writers unless you know the data is text. Initializing `line` to `bw.toString()` is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Readers and Writers unless you know that the data is text. Use InputStreams and OutputStreams, and copy them so:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

Use this logic in both the client and the server.

Notes:

1. It is counterproductive to put a `flush()` inside that loop.
2. If `buffer` is greater than 4096, which it should be, it is pointless to use a `BufferedInputStream`.